# Magento 2: Reduce the width and height of Product image in product detail page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to reduce the width and height of the product image in product detail page magento2?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 product image size and other image options are defined in `<theme_dir>/etc/view.xml`.

Themes located in `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/` folder. `/etc/view.xml` contains images configuration for all storefront product images and thumbnails. You can change it by placing below code in the `view.xml` file between `media` tag.

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
        <image id="product_page_image_small" type="thumbnail">
            <width>88</width>
            <height>116</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
            <width>1000</width>
            <height>1320</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
            <width>1000</width>
            <height>1320</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_small_image" type="small_image">
            <width>220</width>
            <height>220</height>
        </image>
</images>
```

After the changes in the file, please run the deployment commands to reflect the changes on the frontend.

> Resize catalog images

Generally, product images are cached while saving the product. However, the magento catalog:images:resize command enables you to resize all images for display on your storefront.

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

> Get more details on https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Good one, this answer is way more complete than mine! :)

Comment: My image is not resize, it will remain as it is @sumit

Comment: Run php bin/magento catalog:images:resize command and deployment scripts

Comment: yes but no changes

Comment: After this command php bin/magento catalog:images:resize?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the dimensions of images by placing a **view.xml** file in

> "app/design/frontend/"themebuilder"/"themename"/etc"

the file should look something like this:

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
                <width>700</width>
                <height>560</height>
            </image>
        </images>
   </media>
</view>
```